# Windows 7 - Redirect requests to remote http server to localhost

Tags: windows-7, networking, redirection

How can I redirect all requests to a 1.2.3.4:80 to localhost:80? So that everything would be downloaded from my local web server.

- I can't use hosts, because the app is calling the server directly by an IP address
- I don't want to redirect entire traffic of that IP, just the http traffic

There is a game that is downloading all the custom stuff every time I join the server even if I already have that content installed. I just want to fool it, so it's downloading from my local web server, skipping unnecesary internet traffic.

Comment: Answered here [Redirect request to an external IP to localhost (emulate a server)](//serverfault.com/q/171850)

Comment: This is about redirecting all traffic. I just want to redirect HTTP traffic. All other still needs to go to that remote IP.

Comment: I just installed a small Linux machine between me and the router and solved the problem with this: iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 1.2.3.4 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2 but I don't want this Linux machine in between just for this. How to do this locally on Windows?

Comment: Try IP address translation.